# PHP Xpath get input node only with certain attributes

Tags: php, xpath, input

I am trying to parse a HTML document with help of DOM Xpath

I have several input tags in the HTML such as

```
<form id="someid" action="login.jsf">
   <input type="hidden" id="someid" name="somename" value="somevalue">
   <input type="text" id="someid" name="somename" value="somevalue">
</form>
```

I have following code to reach the all the input tags inside form.

```
$inputFields = $xpath->query("//form[contains(@action,'login.jsf')]/input/@*");
```

It returns me all the input nodes with all the attributes but I only need name and value attributes otherwise I will have to run loop around all the attributes and discard all others except name and value. Basically I want to **"select all the input nodes only with name and value attributes."**

I need to create an post array based on name and value attribute values.

I have tried following

```
 $inputFields = $xpath->query("//form[contains(@action,'login.jsf')]/input/[@name | @value]");
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: Do you need the attributes or do you need the tags that have both attributes? Also take note that the union operator does not work inside [the predicate](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#predicates) but (only) for [Node-sets](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#node-sets).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `name` function to get a name of an attribute:

```
//form[contains(@action,'login.jsf')]/input/@*[name()='name' or name()='value']
```